# what is the reason of strange behaviour of typed dataset?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am developing an asp.net website using typed dataset as DAL ,  everything works fine until today I was about to add some new functionality to my website
here is the abstract :

get amount from amount_field from user_table and calculate something then update user_table

here is my sql query for getting amount_field in typed dataset :

```
select userId , Amount from [user] WHERE userId=@userid
```

I named this query : getUserCreditByID(@userid)

and in my BLL I call this query in such this way :

```
public static int getuseramount(long id)
{
    int amount = 0;
    userTableAdapters.userTableAdapter usert = new userTableAdapters.userTableAdapter();
    user.userDataTable userd = usert.GetUserCreditByID(id);
    foreach (user.userRow R in userd)
    {
        amount = R.Amount;
    }
    usert.Dispose();
    userd.Dispose();

    return amount;
}
```

and when I call this function I'll get this error :

> Failed to enable constraints. One or
>   more rows contain values violating
>   non-null, unique, or foreign-key
>   constraints.

but when I change the DAL's sql query into this :

```
SELECT        userID, username, password, address1, address2, tel1, tel2, cell, active, email, showEmail, last_login, Amount, registerdate, websiteUrl, vote, registerIP, city, 
                         firstname, lastname
FROM            [user]
WHERE        (userID = @userid)
```

everything works fine

I am dazed about this , what is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's better to include all of the fields within the user table anyway; maybe because fields were omitted, it inserts null?  Probably a stretch...

Better yet, if you just want those two fields, use an update stored procedure so that you have finer grained control over the update and can update that field correctly.  If you map the update proc to the table, then the update should work fine.

Comment: I guess thats the only answer
there is some issues with typed dataset but they are making my life easy so I don't have to write DAL by myself any longer

Comment: Another alternative (if you have control over the DataSet) would be to create a purpose-built table in your DataSet with just the fields you want in it.

Answer (score 1):

I'll have to take a guess at where the exception get's thrown (take that's an advice to include that in your questions since it makes it easier to give you the correct answer :) )
but I'm guessing it's in this line:

```
user.userDataTable userd = usert.GetUserCreditByID(id);
```

if you userDataTable has constraints there's a very good chance that the returned result is violating some of these since you're in effect only returning a subset of each record which also explains why returning all fields fixes the issue (that would at least hold true if the constraints in the DB are mirrored in the typed dataset)

Comment: this is the exact line that I have problem but I really can't understand where that problem comes form.
so I guess I should add all the record to my datatable then retrieve whatever I want.
regards

Answer (score 1):

You're using a typed DataSet in your DAL, right? If so, you can set the EnforceConstraints property on the DataSet to false for the duration of this query and it should ignore that some of your fields are null.

Comment: even with enforced constraint off I have the same problem